# Angular ng-content not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I want to create a reusable angular component but I face some problem with ng-content. The content that I want to add, it's not apear. 
 Actually I want to use a panel from material and use that panel with different tabs

This is the component with ng-content in it.

```
  <app-panel-section [showTitle]="showTitle" id="content" [noPadding]="true">
  <md-tab-group #tabGroup id="tabGroup" (selectedIndexChange)="selectedIndexChanged($event)" [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex"
    class="collapse in">

    <md-tab [disabled]="true">
      <ng-template md-tab-label>
        <p class="panel-section">
          {{title}}
        </p>
      </ng-template>
    </md-tab>


    <ng-content></ng-content>



  </md-tab-group>
  <div class="tabTitleTools pull-right">
    <i [style.visibility]="!hideAddIcon? '' : 'hidden'" class="fa fa-plus button-like" aria-hidden="true" (click)='addNewItem()'></i>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#tabGroup'">
      <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</app-panel-section>
```

And here is where I want to use it:

```
<app-tabs-group #tabGroup [title]="labels.MEMBERSHIP" [profile]="profile" [showTitle]="false" [hideAddIcon]="hideAddIcon"
[emptyModel]="emptyModel">

 Everything I add here..will not apear. Why ? 
</app-tabs-group>
```

Comment: In my view, my reusable component apear, but the content don't

Comment: Just look at source code of md-tab-group component

Comment: nothing that can help me. Even if I change the app-panel-section directive with a simple div, it won't work

Comment: Seems you didn't look at sources

Comment: It will be very helpful if you could reproduce the issue in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)